# Is it acceptable to have python package names with numbers in it?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I've seen PyPI distribution names as well python package names with numbers in them. For example [flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/)  is one example, where you also import with `import flake8`.

According to PyPI and PEP standards, is it OK to have a number in a package name? I know you can't start with a number for syntax reasons, but is it OK in the middle or the end from a standards viewpoint?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, note that PyPI project names and module names are completely independent; there's nothing stopping you from creating a package `foo` that installs a module `bar`, and these two names follow separate policies as to what is valid.

Module names are restricted by Python's grammar to be valid [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier).  [In Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier), this means that they must consist of an ASCII letter or underscore followed by zero or more ASCII letters, digits, and/or underscores.  In Python 3, Unicode is added, and things get more complicated, but I believe that all-ASCII module names still follow the same restrictions.

The names of projects on PyPI (as specified in [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#names), among others) must consist entirely of ASCII letters, numbers, `.`, `-`, and/or `_`, and they must begin & end with a letter or number.  There is also [a normalization policy](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0503/#normalized-names) that enforces case-insensitivity and treats runs of `.`, `-`, and `_` as equal, so `foo-bar` and `FOO.BAR` are considered the same project.

In addition, [PEP 8 has a section on package and module names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names); it says:

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.
>
> When an extension module written in C or C++ has an accompanying Python module that provides a higher level (e.g. more object oriented) interface, the C/C++ module has a leading underscore (e.g. `_socket`).

So, yes, you can have a number in both a project name and a module name, and the project name can even begin with one!

Comment: Very comprehensive reply. Thank you!